# Linkedin API request dateRange end today or now

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm using Python 3 to request share statistics from Linkedin API for the last 14 months.
It works fine, when I hardcoded the epoch values in the request link:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1596206929000,end:1632938933000),timeGranularityType:DAY)
```

Obviously I don't want to be changing the end values each time I make a request, so I thought I'd declare a variable:

```
from datetime import datetime
epochcdt = datetime.now().timestamp()
```

And then just use it in the link instead of the hardcoded value:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1596206929000,end:epochcdt),timeGranularityType:DAY)
```

But, that doesn't work:

```
{'message': 'Internal Server Error', 'status': 500}
```

Can you please help me with this hopefully, easy to solve problem?

Whole code:

```
import requests
import json
 
from liapiauth import auth, headers
from datetime import datetime

epochcdt = (datetime.now().timestamp())*1000

def organization_info(headers):
    response = requests.get('https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1596206929000,end:{epochcdt}),timeGranularityType:DAY)', headers = headers)
    organization_info = response.json()
    return organization_info
 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    credentials = 'credentials.json'
    access_token = auth(credentials)
    headers = headers(access_token)
    organization_info = organization_info(headers)

with open('lishare14m.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(organization_info, outfile)

print(organization_info)
```

Comment: ```link = f"https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1596206929000,end:{epochcdt}),timeGranularityType:DAY)"``` and then use this variable in your api

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I still get an Internal Server Error. What am I doing wrong?
To make it simpler I edited the first post with current code.

Comment: You need to convert the url in ```requests.get()``` to an [f-string](https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/) ```response = requests.get(f'https://api.linkedin.com/v2/organizationalEntityShareStatistics?q=organizationalEntity&organizationalEntity=urn%3Ali%3Aorganization%3AXXXXX&timeIntervals=(timeRange:(start:1596206929000,end:{epochcdt}),timeGranularityType:DAY)', headers = headers)```